# Hot to get selected text in panel in extjs

Tags: extjs, selection, panel

How to get selected text in panel in extjs?
The panel html property contains some formated html text, but I would like to get only plain text, and not a formated html text. So, if user selects some text, how to get the selection?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'my Panel',
                html: "Some text. Let's say for the sake of this question: <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</i>" ,
                width: 350
                },
                {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'my Button',
                listeners:{
                    click: function(){
                        var selectedText=''; //THIS IS WHERE THE QUESTION IS
                        alert(selectedText);
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window.getSelection().toString() and document.selection.createRange().text

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            defaults: {
                height: 200,
                flex: 1
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                itemId: 'panelOne',
                title: 'Panel One',
                html: "Some <b>text</b>. Let's say for the sake of this question: <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</i>"
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                itemId: 'panelTwo',
                title: 'Panel Two',
                html: "Some <b>text</b>. Let's say for the sake of this question: <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</i>"
            }],
            buttons: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'my Button',
                listeners: {
                    click: function () {
                        var selection = window.getSelection();
                        const panelItemIds = ['panelOne', 'panelTwo'];
                        panelItemIds.forEach(panelItemId => {
                            var panelComponent = this.up('panel').getComponent(panelItemId);
                            var node = selection.baseNode;
                            if (panelComponent) {
                                var panelComponentDom = panelComponent.getEl().dom;
                                while (node !== null) {
                                    if (node == panelComponentDom) {
                                        console.log(`Found selection "${selection.toString()}" in panel "${panelComponent.getTitle()}"`)
                                    }
                                    node = node.parentNode;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Let's say that I have two panels (left and right) , and I would like to know if the text is selected  in left or right panel.